# Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Cannot set readonly property ezcReflectionClass::$class'

Tags: php, call-graph

I am trying to find all the unused code in my project.So  I have gone through many dead code detectors like PHPMD, PHPDCD, Xdebug. Finally i settled with phpcallgraph. I have followed these links: **http://phpcallgraph.sourceforge.net/ http://phpcallgraph.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/phpcallgraph/trunk/readme.txt**
done the same .....

But i ended up with the above error in the below code:

```
   /**
     * Constructs a new ezcReflectionClass object
     *
     * @param string|object|ReflectionClass $argument
     *        Name, instance or ReflectionClass object of the class to be
     *        reflected
     */
    public function __construct( $argument )
    {
        if ( !$argument instanceof ReflectionClass )
        {
            parent::__construct( $argument );
        }
        $this->class = $argument; --> error showing up here
        $this->docParser = ezcReflectionApi::getDocParserInstance();
        $this->docParser->parse( $this->getDocComment() );
    }
```

Tried to figure out but couldnt get my head around it ....Thought someone might have gone through same problem and might have got some solution... THank YOu

Comment: I have the same problem. Probably I will write my own code.

Comment: @Alex Did you ever get a solution for that problem? Would be great if you shared it with us!

Answer (score 1):

I've come into the same problem and analyzing it.

Making `protected $class` and `protected $docParser` into `static protected` and replacing all instances of `$this->class` with `static::$class` and all instances of `$this->docParser` with `static::$docParser` worked.

Comment: I've tried that but it breaks now with strict errors and deprecated methods... :( Looks like this tool is not very well maintained.

Comment: It seems that 'class' is handled as a reserved word. I changed both declarations from "protected" to "public" and renamed 'class' to 'rclass' and it works. But like burzum said, you'll get an extensive list of deprecated and strict errors with PHP 5.4 then. The latest update is dated 2013-05-28, so I think it's not maintained any longer.